# Angular 2 - breaking a service cache

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Using Angular 2, I am importing a service. The service is being cached so any modifications are not applied. I have confirmed this by duplicating the modified service, importing it under a different name, and viewing the changes. How do I break the caching of a service?

Comment: JS browser caching or XHR caching?

Comment: I'm unsure. Disabling the entire cache will solve the problem.

Comment: Where do you define this service? in bootstrap or providers?

Comment: In the providers attribute.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, it's not such a thing as a service cache, the services are dependencies in angular2 and are injected in components, so it can be the same service instance or a new instance(depends how and where it's injected).
Will help if you create a plunker/fiddle or paste here some code.

Comment: Here is a plunker example. However, I am not having the same issue when run through its service.
[plunker.com](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BtvI3FPQCLw93li5vhJ?p=preview)

Comment: Cached when? Between page reloads? There is no service cache. What should the Plunker demonstrate? See https://plnkr.co/edit/7sWWpF?p=preview for an example.